# Matrix increasing integer vector length

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $M \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, such that $M$ has an eigenvalue $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|>1$. Does there always exist a vector $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda > 1$, such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ holds $||M^{lk}x||>\lambda^k||x||$? ($||\cdot||$ is an arbitrary norm). If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$, then of course this holds, but what about $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$?